# Convert Map<String,List<String>> to List<Map<String,String>> in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, functional-programming

`Input: {param1=[x1,y1], param2=[p1,q1],param3=[m1,n1]....}`

`Output: [{param1=x1, param2=p1,param3=m1....},{param1=y1, param2=q1,param3=n1....}]`

I need to convert this input `Map<String,List<String>>` to `List<Map<String,String>>`
Any help is appreciated.
Your help can save my day.. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val source =
    mapOf(
        "param1" to listOf("x1", "y1"),
        "param2" to listOf("p1", "q1"),
        "param3" to listOf("m1", "n1")
    )

val result = source.values.first().indices.map { index ->
    source.entries.associate { (param, list) -> param to list[index] }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm new to fp and have been trying to do the same with zip and i was going no where.